Unknown column "s.ManagerGroup_id" in 'field list'
I'm developing a Maui App with a MySql database. When I do the first interaction with the database, I get this exception:

System.Exception: Unknown column 's.ManagerGroup_id' in field list

I'm using ORM Tags.
ManagerGroup:
[Table("ManagerGroups")]
public class ManagerGroup
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ManagerGroup_id {  get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "char(100)")]
    public required string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Manager> Managers { get; set;} = new List<Manager>();

    public List<Staff> AssignedStaff { get; set;} = new List<Staff>();
}

DbContext class:
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        // Configure logging directly within OnConfiguring
        var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
        {
            builder.AddConsole().SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information); // Add console logging provider
        });

        optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(loggerFactory); // Configure logging
        var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MyDbContext>();
        logger.LogWarning("Logger Ready!");
    }

    // DbSet properties for your database entities
    //public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Manager> Managers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Staff> Staff { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SoS_AnswerSheet> SoS_AnswerSheets { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Staff_SoSList> Staff_SoSLists { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ManagerGroup> ManagerGroups { get; set; }
    // Add more DbSet properties for other entities if needed

    // Junction table config for composite keys
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Staff_SoSList>()
            .HasKey(e => new { e.ManagerGroup_id, e.Staff_id });

        //SoS_AnswerSheet Enum mapping to int
        #region SoS_AnswerSheet Enum mapping
        modelBuilder.Entity<SoS_AnswerSheet>()
            .Property(e => e.Answer1)
            .HasConversion<int>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<SoS_AnswerSheet>()
            .Property(e => e.Answer2)
            .HasConversion<int>();

        // Configure other enum properties similarly
        modelBuilder.Entity<SoS_AnswerSheet>()
            .Property(e => e.Answer3)
            .HasConversion<int>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<SoS_AnswerSheet>()
            .Property(e => e.Answer4)
            .HasConversion<int>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<SoS_AnswerSheet>()
            .Property(e => e.Answer5)
            .HasConversion<int>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<SoS_AnswerSheet>()
            .Property(e => e.Answer6)
            .HasConversion<int>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<SoS_AnswerSheet>()
            .Property(e => e.Answer7)
            .HasConversion<int>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<SoS_AnswerSheet>()
            .Property(e => e.Answer8)
            .HasConversion<int>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<SoS_AnswerSheet>()
            .Property(e => e.Answer9)
            .HasConversion<int>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<SoS_AnswerSheet>()
            .Property(e => e.Answer10)
            .HasConversion<int>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<SoS_AnswerSheet>()
            .Property(e => e.Answer11)
            .HasConversion<int>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<SoS_AnswerSheet>()
            .Property(e => e.Answer12)
            .HasConversion<int>();

        #endregion
    }
}

I checked all tables in the database, and the names are correct and matching with the ones in the app.
I tried figuring it out with logging the SQL queries, but I can't get the Logger to work.
Please consider that I am new to databases. Happy to provide more information if something is needed.
Error Log:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Error: Failed executing DbCommand (27ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT `u`.`User_id`, `u`.`CreatedAt`, `u`.`First_name`, `u`.`Last_name`, `m`.`Manager_id`, `s`.`ManagerGroup_id`, `s`.`staff_id`, CASE
    WHEN `s`.`User_id` IS NOT NULL THEN 'Staff'
    WHEN `m`.`User_id` IS NOT NULL THEN 'Manager'
END AS `Discriminator`
FROM `Users` AS `u`
LEFT JOIN `Managers` AS `m` ON `u`.`User_id` = `m`.`User_id`
LEFT JOIN `Staff` AS `s` ON `u`.`User_id` = `s`.`User_id`
'WaiterEval.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.4\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WaiterEval.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.4\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WaiterEval.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.4\System.IO.Compression.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query: Error: An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'WaiterEval.Services.MyDbContext'.
MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown column 's.ManagerGroup_id' in 'field list'

This is the error log with the SQL query throwing the error.

Even though your error is an sql one, all your sql statements are auto-generated. You need to do debugging to determine which c# line of code generates this error. You can also turn on query logging in mysql on your development server to see what the generated sql looks like.

I managed to get the logging to work. I added the Query that produces the error in the Question.

Does Staff table have s.ManagerGroup_id? If not, you need to determine where ORM gets this column name from and sync it with the database column name.

The database is existing, not created by migrations. For everyone who has the same problem, just chack if EF generates a junction table for a List, but the name is different in your Database.
In my case it was solved by:
    [Table("ManagerGroups")]
    public class ManagerGroup
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ManagerGroup_id {  get; set; }
        // This creates a junction table with Staff
        public List<Staff> AssignedStaff { get; set;} = new List<Staff>();
    }
}

    [Table("Staff")]
    public class Staff : User
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [ForeignKey("User")]
        public int staff_id
        {
            get => User_id;
            set => User_id = value;
        }
        //Option 1 to fix:
        public List<ManagerGroup> managergroups { get; set;} = new List<ManagerGroup>();
    }

Add this to the MyDbContext class
//Option 1:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ManagerGroup>()
        .HasMany(mg => mg.AssignedStaff)
        .WithMany(s => s.ManagerGroups)
        .UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("ManagerGroups_AssignedStaff"));
}
//Option 2: (add a new class to represent the junction table)
public DbSet<ManagerGroup_AssignedStaff> ManagerGroups_AssignedStaff { get; set; }
modelBuilder.Entity<ManagerGroupAssignedStaff>()
    .HasKey(e => new { e.ManagerGroup_id, e.Staff_id });

For Option 2 you also need a new class
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace WaiterEval.Models
{
    [Table("ManagerGroups_AssignedStaff")]
    public class ManagerGroupAssignedStaff
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        public int ManagerGroup_id { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 2)]
        public int Staff_id { get; set; }

    }
}

